# csrf missing error but csrf token is present there i have checked it by inspecting it it is happen in cpanel deployment

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.

More information is available with DEBUG=True.
```

In my django project when i deploy it to c panel its form submission giving me error i have already inclued the csrf token  and also it is working perfectly fine during the development i did some research they were talking about the render function i have used redirect and i had to use

Comment: Did you get any fix for this issue?

Comment: yes i got the fix

Comment: How did you solved it?